# MATLAB unit testing a function call

Tags: matlab, unit-testing

I have the following very simple utility function:

```
function vfprintf(verbose, varargin)
% VFPRINTF Display output optionally depending on the level of verbosity.
%
% VFPRINTF(TF, ARGS) passes the arguments ARGS to the built-in MATLAB
% command |fprintf| if TF is logical true. If TF is logical false, VFPRINTF
% does nothing.

assert(islogical(verbose),...
    'utils:InvalidVerbose',...
    'VERBOSE must be logical true or false');

if verbose
    fprintf(varargin{:});
end
```

It turns out that even though the function is super simple, it had a issue that caused me a problem (the `assert` condition should have been `islogical(verbose) && isscalar(verbose)`, not just `islogical(verbose)`), so I'd like to implement some unit tests around it.

Note that I don't want to test `fprintf` - I'm assuming that's OK. So is there a way that I can test something like:

- "if `verbose` is logical scalar true, then a call is made to `fprintf`"
- "if `verbose` is logical scalar false, then no call is made to `fprintf`"
- "if `verbose` is logical nonscalar, then no call is made to `fprintf`"
- "if `verbose` is not logical, then no call is made to `fprintf`"

I can't find a way to verify that a call is made out to a particular function. Any ideas? The only thing I can think of is to mock out `fprintf` with my own function that shadows the real one on the MATLAB path, which somehow raises an `fprintfCalled` event that is listened to by the testing code to tell when it's called. Is that the only approach? Seems like overkill.

Or perhaps I'm approaching this the wrong way - maybe I should forget about testing the calls that are made, and instead be testing the command-line and/or file output of `vfprintf` directly. But that feels like I'm then testing `fprintf` rather than `vfprintf`.

Maybe I'm overthinking things, but I'd like to improve my testing practices, so would appreciate some advice. Thanks!

Comment: Let me see if I understand: In your unit-testing, you want to make sure that `vfprintf` is used correctly, thus you need to know if `fprintf` was called at any point. Is that right? Can not you check if the file has changed size/been modified?

Comment: @AnderBiguri well two points - firstly I'd like to test outputting to the command line as well as to a file. But secondly, and more relevantly, although I could do that, it feels like I would then be testing `fprintf` rather than `vfprintf`. Ideally I want to just rely on `fprintf`, and just test that a call is made to it. (But perhaps you'd advise that that would be a bad practice for unit testing, I don't know).

Comment: I am very far from an expert on unit testing, so do not rely on what I say fully. However, I believe that for unit testing, you should not modify the function, else you are "cheating". If you test that the file has been modified (or that something has been written in command line, this is easy to do) then you are testing `vfprintf` because it will not always be printed, it depends on `verbose`. Thus you are not testing if `fprintf` can do all the jobs its supposed to do correctly, bu `vfprintf`. A unit test of `fprintf` would be *way* bigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think at this point you really have 4 options. I like the 4th, but I'll run through them all:

1. Execute your calls to vfprintf within an evalc to validate what is printed to the command window or create a file and print to that file. Drawbacks 1:  kind of tests fprintf (athough its more academic since there is very low chance that fprintf will change significantly or not honor its contract). Drawback 2: Both cases interact with global state - either the global command window output (which other things can print to) or the filesystem. Not the end of the world, but good to avoid if you can. It would be much nicer for your test to completely avoid touching the outside world.
2. Shadow the fprintf function. You can do this by putting it in a folder off the path and then adding your own fprintf function in that folder, then using a [PathFixture](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.fixtures.pathfixture-class.html?searchHighlight=pathfixture) in your test to add it to the top of the path. Drawback: Still relies on changing global state (the path) and it may be slower because path manipulation is expensive from a language execution perspective. Not a big fan, but here is how this might play out. If you can I'd suggest going with #4 below over this:

***VerboseArgumentsHolder.m***

```
    classdef VerboseArgumentsHolder < handle
        properties
            Arguments = {};
        end
    end
```

***VerbosePrinterSpy.m***

```
    classdef VerbosePrinterSpy
        properties(Constant)
            ArgumentsHolder = VerboseArgumentsHolder;
        end
    end
```

*** (test folder)/overloads/fprintf/fprintf.m***

```
   function fprintf(varargin)
   argHolder = VerbosePrinterSpy.ArgumentsHolder;
   argHolder.Arguments = varargin;
   end
```

***vfprintfTest.m***

```
    classdef vfprintfTest < matlab.unittest.TestCase
        methods(Test)
            function testWhenScalarTrue(testCase)
                import matlab.unittest.fixtures.PathFixture;

                testCase.applyFixture(PathFixture(...
                    fullfile((test folder),'overloads','fprintf')));

                argHolder = VerbosePrinterSpy.ArgumentsHolder;
                argHolder.Arguments = {}; % reset values since this is global and stateful.
                vfprintf(true,'dummy input');
                testCase.verifyEqual(argHolder.Arguments, 'dummy input');
            end
            function testWhenScalarFalse(testCase)

                testCase.applyFixture(PathFixture(...
                    fullfile((test folder),'overloads','fprintf')));

                argHolder = VerbosePrinterSpy.ArgumentsHolder;
                argHolder.Arguments = {}; % reset values

                vfprintf(false,'dummy input');
                testCase.verifyEmpty(argHolder.Arguments);
            end
        end
    end
```

3. Restructure your production code to have an interface for printing, then you can add a test specific spy as that interface. This is a nice approach, but has an implication on your software structure that may not be all that easy to adjust to , especially if your codebase is already heavily reliant on this utility.
4. Since you are just passing on the varargin to fprintf directly, then you can create a test double with an fprintf method to specifically test this out. Then, the fprintf call would dispatch to your testing specific class which can simply spy on the inputs. It may look something like this:

***VerbosePrinterSpy.m***

```
    classdef VerbosePrinterSpy < handle
        properties
            WasInvoked = false;
            ArgumentsUsedInPrintCall = {'Not invoked'};
        end

        methods
            function fprintf(spy, varargin)
                spy.WasInvoked = false;
                spy.ArgumentsUsedInPrintCall = varargin;
            end
        end
    end
```

***vfprintfTest.m***

```
    classdef vfprintfTest < matlab.unittest.TestCase
        methods(Test)
            function testWhenScalarTrue(testCase)
                spy = VerbosePrinterSpy;
                vfprintf(true, spy, 'dummy input');
                testCase.verifyTrue(spy.WasInvoked);
                testCase.verifyEqual(spy.ArgumentsUsedInPrintCall, 'dummy input');
            end
            function testWhenScalarFalse(testCase)
                spy = VerbosePrinterSpy;
                vfprintf(false, spy, 'dummy input');
                testCase.verifyFalse(spy.WasInvoked);
            end
        end
    end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Andy. So 1 I agree seems dirty, and 3 would be great, but `vfprintf` is unfortunately littered throughout the code. 4 is ingenious and looks like it would be perfect here, but it seems like it only works because I happen to be passing the `varargin` directly through. If I were to pursue 2, what would be the best way to get my shadowed `fprintf` to report back to the testCase that it had been called (and its arguments)?

Comment: You'd have to use persistent variables or some collaborator with a Constant property that holds onto a handle. Basically you would need to reset that global state in the test, and then in your fprintf overload you would store the record of the input arguments in the handle stored in the Constant property. A bit of a hack, which is a point against this approach, but it would be for a class that is only used for this particular test. Let me know if you'd like to see an example and maybe I can add some code.

Comment: No need for an example - I see what you're suggesting. I'll try approaches 2 and 4 and see which feels best. Thanks again Andy.

Comment: Couldn't help myself ;-)

Comment: This may amuse you - my tests are now passing when I use `TestRunner.withNoPlugins`, but failing when I run `TestRunner.withTextOutput('Verbosity', 4)`. If you give it a moment's thought, I'm sure you'll guess why, and then facepalm :). Please don't waste any more of your time trying to help me deeper into this hole I'm digging for myself...

Comment: Haha which approach? The path overloads one? yes, when using this approach sometimes you may need to watch out for what global functions the test framework itself is calling. Another con to the path approach. Good luck, and have fun! Option 4 works regardless of what/who is calling the builtin fprintf :-)